# Implementation of stack using pointers

Tags: c++, beginner, stack, collections, pointers

Please review my code and let me know how I can possibly improve it.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class node
{
    private:
                    int data;
    public:
                  node *next;
                    node(int element)
                    {
                            data=element;
                            next=NULL;
                    }
                    int getdata()
                    {
                        return(data);
                    }                               
};

class stack
{
    private:
                    node *start;
    public:
                    void push(int element);
                    int pop();
                    void traverse();
                    stack()
                    {
                        start=NULL;
                    }
};

inline void stack::push(int element)
{
    node *ptr;
    node *temp=start;
    ptr=new node(element);
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=ptr;
        ptr->next=NULL;

    }
    else
    {
            while(temp->next!=NULL)
            {
                temp=temp->next;    
            }
            temp->next=ptr;
            ptr->next=NULL; 
    }
}

inline int stack::pop()
{
    node *temp=start;
    node *top=start;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    while(top->next!=temp)
    {
        top=top->next;
    }
    top->next=NULL;
    int item=temp->getdata();
    delete (temp);
}

inline void stack::traverse()
{
    node *temp=start;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"data is"<<temp->getdata();
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{  
  stack a;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a.push(i);
    }
    a.traverse();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        a.pop();
    }
    a.traverse();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Indenting seems very haphazard.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (noob here), but I thought we were forbidden to use loops and if/else statements in inline functions.

Comment: next step - make it generic so that is supports a stack of any type

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, I will start with one of the most common remarks: please, [do not use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1364752). It is especially bad if you write it in a header file since it leads to namespace pollution and name clashes.

---

Instead of a method named `traverse`, it would be better to overload `operator<<` to print your list. Here is how you could adapt your function (put that code in your class):

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const stack& sta)
{
    node *temp= sta.start;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        stream<<"data is"<<temp->getdata();
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Don't forget to make it a `friend` function so that it can access the `private` members of `stack`.

---

Generally speaking, you shouldn't mark your functions `inline`. While it *may* sometimes speed up your code for small functions (your functions aren't small), most of the time, it will simply ***be totally ignored by the compiler***. Even if it is taken into account by the compiler for inlining, it could still [make your executable larger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145952/1364752) and will probably not significantly speed up your code. *Worse*: since `inline` functions have to live in the header file, you will have to compile again every file including this one when you change the implementation of your functions. Bottom line: remove all your `inline` qualifications, they won't gain you anything and may make things worse.

---

From the implementation of `pop`, I bet that it is meant to return the popped `int` since you called `getdata`. However, you forgot to return `item`. Your compiler should have warned you about the unused variable `item` and the non-void function `pop` returning nothing. If not, you should tell your compiler to give you more warnings.

---

You don't need to write `return 0;` at the end of the function `main` in C++. If nothing has been returned when the end of the function is reached, it automagically does `return 0;`. This remark only holds for the function `main` though. Also, you don't need to put parenthesis around the returned result; `return` is not a function.

Comment: :thanks a lot. I am a beginner, learning to write c++ code.This has helped me a lot.

Comment: Marking your functions `inline` will have no affect on the size or speed of your code. For `code-inlining` purposes the keyword `inline` is ignored by modern compilers (unless you explicitly force the compiler to use the hints). Humans are terrible at knowing when to inline code as a result compiler writers have long stopped trusting them and use pretty good huristics.

Comment: @LokiAstari Well, I was only quoting an answer on a reference question... And I actually just saw you comment on the aforementioned question.

Comment: using `using` is fine if it's not in a header file. Personally I think writing 'std::' everywhere looks quite messy in a source file. The whole point of namespaces is that you don't have to prefix symbols with something unique anymore.

Answer (score 15):

- Please fix your indentation all over the header.  It should be consistent with everything else.
- You don't need the `return 0` at the end of `main()`.  Reaching this point implies successful termination, and the compiler will just insert it for you.
- In common stack implementations, `pop()` is `void` (merely pops off the top element).  This is useful as it'll be much easier to terminate the function early if the stack is empty.

  For getting an element from the top, you would also have a `top()` function.  It will also have to account for an empty stack, but it would be best to check for an empty list first.
- As @ChrisW has mentioned, the `node` class should be defined within the `stack` class as `private`.  Also, there shouldn't be anything `public` inside the `node` class.  If you put it within `stack`, its `private` data can still be accessed without an accessor.
- A member function like `getdata()` should be `const` as it doesn't modify any data members.  You also don't need the `()` around `data`.

  ```
  int getdata() const
  {
      return data;
  }
  ```

  Moreover, you shouldn't have this function at all.  A basic node structure should just have a data field and a pointer to the next/previous node in the list.  As mentioned, anything containing this class will have access to its data.
- Prefer an initializer list instead of the constructor assignments:

  ```
  node(int element) : data(element), next(NULL) {}
  ```

  One advantage to this is that if you have any `const` data members, you'll be able to initialize them within this list.  But with a constructor like yours, that won't work.
- You *must* have a destructor for a data structure that utilizes manual memory allocation.  What happens if your structure object goes out of scope, but you haven't already popped every element?  You'll have a memory leak.

  To prevent this, have the destructor traverse the list, using `delete` on each node.
- You can make your structure more intuitive and safer with a `empty()` function:

  ```
  bool empty() const { start == NULL; }
  ```

  This can just be defined within the class declaration and should be `public`.

  It is assumed that the list is empty if the head points to `NULL`, otherwise you can instead compare a size member to `0` (if you even want to bother with maintaining a size).

Answer (score 9):

You could improve your use of whitespace; perhaps something more like this:

```
class node
{
private:
    int data;
public:
    node *next;
    node (int element)
    {
        data = element;
        next = NULL;
    }
    int getdata() const
    {
        return data;
    }                               
};
```

The `node` class might be named `Node` instead (I usually use PascalCase for types and camelCase for identifiers).

`node` has public `data` member. I think it would be better if `node` were a private, nested type of `stack` (i.e. defined within and only usable by the `stack` class).

`traverse` could be `const` since it doesn't modify the data.

Instead of `if { ... } else { ... }` I usually prefer `if { ... return; } ...`.

You don't need to set ptr->next to NULL twice (once in the constructor and again in the `push` function).

`NULL` is deprecated in C++ (prefer `0`).

Your push and pop are inefficient because you push and pop from the end of the list; you can push and pop from the beginning of the list instead.

Comment: I know `nullptr` is the new preferred null pointer, but why is `0` better than `NULL`?

Comment: @200_success Apparently the standard now does `#define NULL 0` ... so `NULL` is the same as `0` ... but `NULL` is a (unnecessary/useless) C-style macro ... see e.g. http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null ... Perhaps `NULL` used to cause problems years ago when a "C/C++" compiler defined it as `#define NULL (void*)0` and so NULL couldn't be assigned to e.g. a variable of type `char*`.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to push/pop at the start of the list rather than the end.  For large stacks this is a major speed improvement.

Comment: I have to disagree with 0 over `NULL`. `NULL` conveys meaning that 0 doesn't. Though the same as 0, `NULL` still mentally screams "hey this is a pointer!" I tend to agree that macros are evil, but I think `NULL` is an exception. `T* ptr = 0;` just doesn't have the same mental effect on me that `T* ptr = NULL;` does. Not to mention that compilers are still allowed to generate notices about `NULL`. A compiler can still have internal special meaning for `NULL` and treat it like it's a pointer type just in warning form instead of an error.

Answer (score 3):

it would be better if you start putting comments as it makes a better and understandable code!!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You're correct about that, but in the future, please try to write more detailed answers. You could, for example, explain what kind of comments you would put in their code.